# Посоветуйте мануал по регулярным выражениям

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пишу парсер, регулярные не знаю вообще.
Очень нужно кратко, быстро, ясно. Ну не статью в интернете (хотя если хорошая - шлите), и не три тома. Надеюсь, Вы поняли меня).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть книжка Фридл Д. Регулярные выражения. Там около 550 стр.

Если совсем кратко, то, помню, в книжке Шварц, Феникс и фон Брайан. Изучаем Perl была достаточно краткая и очень хорошая глава по регуляркам. Но там все, естественно, на перле.

Comment: Для относительно быстрого понимания сути регулярных выражений достаточно прочитать первые 40 (или около того) страниц из Фридла. Оставшуюся часть книги можно использовать как справочник по особенностям реализации регулярных выражений в разных языках/библиотеках, и других особенностях, связанных с юникодом, ретроспективными и обратными провекрами и т.п.

Так что Фридл, наверное, лучший выбор.

Answer (score -1):

Regular Expressions: A Brief Tutorial
by Dorothea Salo

[Мануал с подробным пояснением и заданиями](http://misc.yarinareth.net/regex.html)